# Error with LINQ to typed dataset. "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type.."

Tags: c#, linq

Using VS2008 & .NET 3.5. I am getting an error message "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'xxx.BuildingsDataTable'.  'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'building''. (xxx is a namespace)

my linq query:

```
var query = from building in buildingDS.Buildings
                            where building.BuildingID == 1
                            select new { building.Name };
```

buildingDS is a typed dataset. VS can intellisense buildingDS but it can't intellisense building (buildingID & Name are in red). I have references to System.Data.Linq, System.Data.DataSetExtensions & System.Core. EnforceConstraints for the dataset = true. I tried casting building to the dataRow type but it didn't work. Not sure what it wants me to do with 'building'.

How do I get the query to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your typed dataset has been processed by the new .Net 3.5 generator.
Each table class should inherit `TypedTableBase<TRow>`.

If your table class inherits `DataTable` directly, regenerate the typed dataset.

Also, make sure that your code file contains `using System.Data`.

Comment: Thanks. Although WSDL generated typed datasets do not support TypedTableBase. The datasets are regular datasets. They are supported in WCF but not asmx. So I guess i can't use LINQ to typed datasets.

Comment: @Tony: You can still write `from building in buildingDS.Buildings.Rows.Cast<BuildingData.BuildingsRow>()`.  You can wrap that up in an extension method for each table.